# C++ class member same identifier as member function argument

Tags: c++, identifier

Can a C++ class member function's argument have the same identifier (name) as a member data of the same class?

My method for dealing with this was to use the `this` pointer, however I am not sure the code will compile as expected;

For example:

```
class M {

    [public/private:]
    int i;

    void add(int i)
    {
        (this->i) = ((this->i) + i);

        return;
    }
}
```

Quite a strange example, but it demonstrates the principle. Are the parentheses required?

Comment: The parentheses are not required in your example. In fact, I'd say they harm readability.

Comment: @T.C. Thought they were not, but couldn't be sure.

Comment: It's still bad style. Try not to hide names like that. (Personally, when I need a parameter and a member to have the same name, a common occurrence in constructors, I add a `_` suffix to the end of he parameter name.)

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I was doing that at one point, it is a good solution. However I started to get confused when I started using an `_` before the name for member data. That results in difficult to read statements such as `_pointer_to_b = pointer_to_b_` or worse, if returning values through arguments `pointer_to_b_ = _pointer_to_b`. Now that's confusing.

Comment: @user3728501: That's why people who feel the need to prefix members use the `m_` prefix instead. Also, `_`-prefixed symbols are sometimes reserved by libraries.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Indeed, however then you have an ugly "m" to look at all day, not very inviting...

Comment: A leading underscore is just as ugly. I don't use either. IMHO, if you need coding conventions to tell the difference between class members and local variables or parameters, your class and/or method is too complex and should be refactored.

Answer (score 2):

As Jarod42 told you, the code is valid without parentheses.

An alternative way, not using `this` is to use scope resolution operator `::` :

```
class M {

public:
    int i=0;   // better initialize it, if you do not have a constructor. 

    void add(int i)
    {
        M::i = M::i + i;  // the i belonging to class M vs. parameter i 

        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: And it works also when a derived class has a member with the same name than the base class

Comment: @Christophe Thanks, that's useful to know

Answer (score 1):

The code is valid, and parentheses are not required.

In addition, you may also have

```
class M
{
public:
    explicit M(int i) : i(i) {} // initialize member with method argument as expected.

private:
    int i;
};
```

Comment: Could do with `;` after the class definition.

Comment: @xmoex: Why do you want to have the add method for example code ?

Comment: The additional code (constructor) [might create confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/509868), unless supplemented with the `explicit` keyword

Comment: @xmoex: The example is obviously just about how initialisation lists differ from function parameters. It does not intend to replace the add function.

Comment: What is the general rule for adding `explicit`? It is at any time when the constructor can take a _single argument which is of type int, double, float, char, etc_.

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, but you could just use:

```
void add(int i) {
    this->i += i;
}
```

as you don't need parenthesis, also the `+=` doesn't make it look so ugly. And btw: you don't need an explicit return statement as the method returns upon completion automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> however I am not sure the code will compile as expected;

Why don't you just try it?

Anyway, the answer is: yes, it will.

It's just that if you run into this problem very often, chances are that your identifiers could be longer or more descriptive. `i` is hardly an acceptable name for a function parameter or member variable.

You will also find that many coding standards require you to distinguish member variables from function parameters, e.g. by prepending all member variables with `m_`. In that case, your `i` member variable would become `m_i`. These are stylistic issues, with the potential of creating heated discussions.

The parentheses in your example are redundant. Sometimes, redundant parentheses enhance readability of code, but in this case I don't think so. And of course, using the `+=` operator further simplifies the code:

```
void add(int i)
{
    this->i += i;

    return;
}
```

Comment: By compile as expected I meant that I know it _will_ compile, but didn't know whether `i` would refer to the argument or the data member.